# Questions about the efficiency of the operations of insertion, lookup, and deletion?

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

The answers are (2) and (3) but I am not sure why. I don’t have a lot of information to go off of on data structures. Can someone explain why these answers are correct and why the others are incorrect.
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) Incorrect. Let's just take a small example with an array of size `10` Regardless if the array is sorted or not, if you remove the 5th element, you will have to move 6 so it becomes 5, move 7 so it becomes 6, and so on.

2) Correct. A double-linked list is a list where each object holds a pointer to the previous and the next object . Let's take the element `i` For educational purposes, consider that [i + 1] is the next object and [i - 1] is the previous object (as if we were inside an array)

```
list[i].pPrevious = list[i - 1];
list[i].pNext = list[i + 1]
```

To remove the object `i` from the list, you just have to make sure the previous object points to the next object, and vice-versa.

```
list[i - 1].pNext = list[i + 1];
list[i + 1].pPrevious = list[i - 1];
```

After that you just need to delete the object itself, but it no longer belongs in the list.

3) Correct, worst case would be having a tree that is only on the left, or only on the right. This implies you have to traverse the whole tree to find the object you're looking for. It's done in  O(n), and it's the same as trying to get the last object of a list.

4) Incorrect. It will only be O(1) if the object you're trying to insert/find/delete is the first (and only) object of the tree. Usual case requires to traverse the tree and that averages to O(log n)

5) See `1)`